# Transform offsets input border in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

I was making a webpage and I needed to horizontally and vertically align a `div` with an `input`, in the center of the page. But when I tested the code it rendered something I didn't expect. [image]

```css
body {
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Source Sans Pro;
  line-height: 160%;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  background: #E6E6E6;
  padding: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div><input /></div>
```

I tested it in Chrome and Firefox, but this bug only happens in Chrome. Is there a reason for this, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input` element is, by default, styled with an `inset` value:

[image]

Try this instead:

```css
input { border: 1px solid gray; }

body {
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Source Sans Pro;
  line-height: 160%;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  background: #E6E6E6;
  padding: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div><input /></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It fixed my problem, but the border looks like it has 3px width. Why is that?

Comment: It's actually a 1px border. But when the `border-style` is `inset`, it shifts about 50% of the `border-width` off-screen, so it looks thinner.